# Can I use the touchpad for scrolling instead of the trackpoint on a thinkpad?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, scrolling, trackpoint

I can use my thinkpad's middle mouse button to scroll by holding it and using the trackpoint in the center of the keyboard to control speed.  Is there a way I can reconfigure this so that, while holding the button, I can use the touchpad to scroll? Similar to edge scrolling, but while the middle mouse button is being held down.

`xev` reports it as mouse button 2 and I can successfully remap it to other commands/behaviors using xbindkeys, but I am unsure how to implement the touchpad/scrolling part.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10.